# Laravel: Populating forms while still allowing Form::old()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

What's the best way to populate forms with database data made using the Form class in Laravel while still giving way to `Input::old()` if there are any errors? I can't seem to get it right.

My current setup looks something like this

```
public function getSampleform() {
    // Load database data here

    return View::make('sampleform');
}

public function postSampleform() {
    // Save to database again then redirect to success page

    return Redirect::to('success');
}
```

I usually echo my fields in the View this way:

```
<?php echo Form::text('entry', Input::old('entry'), array('class' => 'form-select'); ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to do this is using Form Model Binding (http://four.laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding):

Use an existing model or create an 'empty' model class:

```
class NoTable extends Eloquent { 
    protected  $guarded = array();
}
```

Find your model or instantiate your empty class and fill it with data:

```
public function getSampleform() {
    // Load database data here

    $model = new NoTable;
    $model->fill(['name' => 'antonio', 'amount' => 10]);

    return View::make('sampleform')->with(compact('model'));
}
```

If you'll use your form with a table that you already have data on it, this is how you uset it:

```
public function getSampleform() {

    // Locate the model and store it in a variable:
    $model = User::find(1);

    // Then you just pass it to your view:   
    return View::make('sampleform')->with(compact('model'));
}
```

To have your form populated, use Form Model Binding, this is an example in Blade:

```
{{ Form::model($model, array('route' => array('sample.form')) ) }}
    {{ Form::text('name') }}
    {{ Form::text('amount') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

You don't even have to pass your Input data, because Laravel will populate your inputs using what comes first:

```
1 - Session Flash Data (Old Input)
2 - Explicitly Passed Value (wich may be null or not)
3 - Model Attribute Data
```

And Laravel will also take care of csrf token for you, using Form::open() or Form::model().

Comment: I never knew about the `Form::model` command. I'm obviously missing a few L4 details but where did you get the `sample.form` value used in the view?

Comment: I take it back. It's a named route.

Comment: can anyone comment why an empty model class is required? Why not use the model class of the database being accessed?

Comment: @EricCope, it's better to use an actual model class of the database being accessed, question was this way because of the example the user gave us. But you're right and I just edited the answer to also provide a better database example.

Comment: If you expect `Input::old` input to show up, make sure you include `->withInput(Input::all())` in your controller.

Comment: What will be the proper way to create this case in Laravel 5.2? What to put in blade old('name') or $model->name, to get model data on form load and session old input on next (if error)?

Answer (score 3):

The `old()` helper in Laravel (at least in 5.0) allows for a default value so that if some default value `$entry` is defined, then if you do this:

```
<?php 
    echo Form::text('entry', Input::old('entry', $entry), array('class' => 'form-select'); 
?>
```

The helper will first try to look up the old form value and failing that will use the value `$entry`. This also avoids having to use a ternary operator in your code.

However, when doing the redirect and there is an error you have to re-bind the old input data so that your `postSampleform()` method would look like:

```
public function postSampleform() {

    // Save to database again then redirect to success page
    if ($success)
    {
        return Redirect::to('success');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('sampleform')->withInput(Request::all());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is amazing. I had no idea ```Input::old()``` took a second argument!

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass old input from the controller (`$entry` should contain your database entry):

```
return View::make('sampleform')->with('entry', $entry)->with_input();
```

And then in the view, use an inline if statement to load the input if present, or else load from database:

```
Form::text('entry', Input::old('entry') ? Input::old('entry') : $entry, array('class' => 'form-select');
```

Comment: But how do I populate it with data from a database query the first time the page is loaded?

Comment: See updated answer.  My answer is for Laravel 3, the other answer from Melvin is basically the same, but for Laravel 4.

Comment: Small tip; the ternary you used can be shortend to:
`Form::text('entry', Input::old('entry') ?: $entry, array('class' => 'form-select');`

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

```
// Check first if there is data from database else blank
$entry = (isset($data->entry)) ? $data->entry : '';
<?php echo Form::text('entry', isset(Input::old('entry')) ? Input::old('entry') : $entry, array('class'=>'form-select')); ?>
```

Then in your controller, you can do this:

```
public function getSampleform() {
    // Load database data
    $data = "Database data here";
    return View::make('sampleform', compact('data'));
}

public function postSampleform() {
    // validate

    // if validation fails
    // redirect back and pass old inputs
    return Redirect::to('getSampleform')->withInput();
}
```

Take note that this is for Laravel 4..
Hope this works for you.. Cheers...